# erc20 transfer SafeMath: subtraction overflow?

Tags: web3js, parity

I am trying to transfer a erc20 token.

```
   const data = contract.methods.transfer(recipient, amount).encodeABI();   
   const rawTx = {
        from: sender,
        nonce: '0x' + count.toString(16),
        gasPrice: this.web3.utils.toHex(2000000000),
        gasLimit: estimateGas,
        to: contracts.address,
        value: '0x0',
        data: data,
        chainId: '0x' + contracts.chainId
      };
      console.log(rawTx);

      const privKeyBuffer = new Buffer.from(senderPrivateKey, 'hex');
        const tx = new EthereumTx(rawTx);
        tx.sign(privKeyBuffer);
        const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
        const signedTransaction =  '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
        console.log(signedTransaction);
```

but when I try to `trace_rawTransaction`, to see if the transaction is alright, I get this output:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "output": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e536166654d6174683a207375627472616374696f6e206f766572666c6f770000",
        "stateDiff": null,
        "trace": [
            {
                "action": {
                    "callType": "call",
                    "from": "0x...",
                    "gas": "0x7470",
                    "input": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000004b346650ea60d22583c9e47a44b49120ae2638250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000",
                    "to": "0x...",
                    "value": "0x0"
                },
                "error": "Reverted",
                "subtraces": 0,
                "traceAddress": [],
                "type": "call"
            }
        ],
        "vmTrace": null
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

The output is :

```
SafeMath: subtraction overflow
```

What is happening?

Comment: What is `data`???

Comment: const data = contract.methods.transfer(recipient, amount).encodeABI();, transfer is a ERC20 function in the ABI file.

Comment: hm, do you have enough balance to transfer that amount plus gas fee?

Comment: What is the implementation of `transfer`? (I'm trying to guide you to the point where you realize that the subtraction overflow is in that function, where you should be able to easily understand why you're getting it).

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Yes I have enough balance and gas.

Comment: @goodvibration, it is a erc20 transfer, the abi for transfer is {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event"
  }

Comment: Where is this function implemented? What is its source code? Surely you must have some idea about either one (and hopefully both) of these questions!

Comment: @goodvibration, I just use openzeppelin to create the token,  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";, it is deploy to a Parity POA localhost.

Comment: Then do some minimal effort to look into their code, it's not that complicated. Also, since it's relevant to the question, you should by the least post the code of that function in here, because the "subtraction underflow" is obviously triggered from that contract.